# Fix null IMEI on rooted phone without pc

Tags: root-access, imei

So, the biggest drawback is I can't connect phone to PC (drivers not installing on Win 10, separate issue). And in my current ROM, I have already got root setup. Problem is I am getting null imei.

As you understand, I cannot go back to stock, or make any changes in this setup. Because if I mess it up, I can't connect to PC to fix it. I can however copy files to sd card and fix the imei that way.

How can I add the imei info using rooted phone, without a pc?

Edit:

I tried MTK engineering mode app as well. But the engineering mode contains no option for radio information.

Comment: Have you tried xposed imei changer? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vivek.imeichanger

Comment: tried it just now. app keeps closing. tried chamelophon, and for that changes are not sticking. after reboot, imei becomes null again and again

Comment: Your phone's EFS partition(s) is probably damaged. You may want to download the stock ROM and flash that partition.

Comment: Okay, I tried that too. After starting from scratch, same issue. But funny thing is a specific rom works fine, the one I was using earlier. Any other rom gives me this problem.